# Filter out df by a row in another df

Tags: python, pandas

I have two data frames. One contains the list of files (let's say this is df1) along with some data, and another one contains the list of files that I want (let's say this is df2). I want to create another df that contains only the wanted files and their data.

Any help is appreciated:))

df1:

[image]

df2:

[image]

Wanted_df

[image]

Comment: Cool. show your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following code modified to deal with modified df1. It's rather clunky with all the working apparent but it works. I have no time to make it sleeker.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'File path': ['<filepath>/File 1', '<Filepath>/File 2', '<Filepath>/File 3','<Filepath>/File 4' , '<Filepath>/File 5'],
                   'Data about that file': ['apple', 'orange', 'strawberry', 'pineapple', 'starfruit']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'List of Wanted Files': ['File 1', 'File 3', 'File 5']})

a = df1['File path'].values
b = df2['List of Wanted Files'].values


mydict = {x: (False,) for x in range(len(a))}

for count, i in enumerate(a):
    for j in b:
        if j in i:
            mydict[count] = (True, j)
info = list(mydict.values())

mask = [x[0] for x in info]

wanted_df = pd.DataFrame([x[1] for x in info if x[0]], columns = ['File Name'])
s = df1['Data about that file'][mask].reset_index(drop = True)
wanted_df['Data about that file'] = s

print(wanted_df)
```

which produces:

```
  File Name Data about that file
0    File 1                apple
1    File 3           strawberry
2    File 5            starfruit
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge them together by doing this:

```
wanted_df = df1.merge(df2, how = "right", left_on = 'File name', right_on = 'List of Wanted Files')
```

Comment: Thank you! I've made a change to df1, will this work with the new df1?

Comment: Yes, but if you change the name of  columns, make sure to exchange them in the code as well)

Comment: I think I'm running into a problem where each <filepath> is different, so the program isn't finding anything in common between the two df.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
Wanted_df = df1[df1['File Name'].isin(df2['List of Wanted Files'])]
```

which produces:

```
  File Name Data about that File
0    File 1                apple
2    File 3           strawberry
4    File 5            starfruit
```

Comment: Thank you so much:)  I've made a change to df1, will this work with the new df1?

Comment: See additional answer.